# how to store value of every iteration in an array in state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm iterating over each question in a data set however I want to store the value of each iteration in an array to store in the state so I basically need all the questions in an array.

I'm currently receiving every question logged in the console one after the other but in the state It's only storing one question. I want to display all of the questions with the answers for each question but I'm not sure how to do this.

My data set resembles this:

````
[{"id":1,"question":"...":[{"id":1,"answer":"..."},{"id":2,"answer":"..."}]},{"id":2,"question":"...","answers":[{"id":1,"answer":""},{"id":2,"answer":""},{"id":3,"answer":""}]} ...}]```
````

```
// the entire data set
 const [questionsData, setQuestionsData] = useState<any>([])
// the actual questions
  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState<[]>([])
  const [answers, setAnswers] = useState<[]>([])

useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/...")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setQuestionsData(data))
    }, []);
  
    useEffect(() => {
      if (questionsData.length > 0) {
        for (let i = 0, l = questionsData.length; i < l; i++) {
          setAnswers(questionsData[i].answers)
          setQuestions(questionsData[i].question)
          console.log(questionsData[i].question)
        }
            }
     
    
    }, [questionsData, answers])
    

  return (
      <p>{JSON.stringify(questions)}</p>
 <p>{JSON.stringify(answers)}</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that duplicating state is indeed what you want to do in the first place (there are use cases for it, such as separtely tracking "original" data and "modified" data, so I'll assume you're doing something like that)...

You don't really need a loop.  Instead, just use `.map()` to project the array into the new shape and store that new shape in state:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (questionsData.length > 0) {
    setAnswers(questionsData.map(q => q.answers));
    setQuestions(questionsData.map(q => q.question));
  }
}, [questionsData, answers]);
```

In fact, since `questionsData` is by default an empty array, which would produce an empty array with `.map()`, you don't even need the `if` condition at this point:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setAnswers(questionsData.map(q => q.answers));
  setQuestions(questionsData.map(q => q.question));
}, [questionsData, answers]);
```

**However**, you probably **do** want to remove `answers` from the dependency array since this effect *modifies `answers`*:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setAnswers(questionsData.map(q => q.answers));
  setQuestions(questionsData.map(q => q.question));
}, [questionsData]);
```